# f:form.select does not show me the data

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-flow

I have an object adherent that contains an object grade(Class: Grade, membres: $uid,$abelGrade). I want to display all grades in database table 'grade'. so I assign a grades (an array of grades) to my view and i write this code :

```
<f:form.select property="grade" value="{adherent.grade.labelGrade}" options="{grades}" optionValueField="uid" optionLabelField="labelGrade" size="1" id="category" />
```

but the problem it doesn't display anything. what could be the problem?

Comment: I am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be missing $grade->getUid() and $grade->getLabelGrade() methods. These are called due to the optionValueField and optionLabelField. If thats not the problem, set a breakpoint where you assign the {grades} array to the view and check if it's really an array or an ObjectStorage. Thats everything I can think of right now, maybe you'd like to provide some further code.